# How do I create a unique ID based on an array of numbers so that the value of various combination of different numbers are not the same?

Tags: php, arrays, math, hash

I have a list called users_id in an array

```
array(1,2,3,4...25)
```

If I combine 7 and 3, the value produced cannot be the same as 6 and 4. However, if I combine 3 and 7, the combined value is the same as 7 and 3 and this is acceptable.

So addition cannot be used because the combination of 7,3 and 6,4 will still produce the same value, 10. Multiplication also can't be used because 5 x 2 is the same as 1 x 10. The same rule applies to 1  number or more than 2 numbers up till 25 combination of **different numbers**.

In other words, two different combination of numbers cannot produce the same combined value **if and only if** the numbers used are **not the same**.

**My aim** is to produce a unique conversations_id based on an array of users_id so that the application can decide **whether a conversation between the same kind of users has already existed**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably a hash based on a *sorted* array:

```
sort($userIds);
$conversationId = sha1(json_encode($userIds));
```

The `json_encode` is just an arbitrary serialisation format to convert the array into a string that can be hashed. You could also `join(',')` it or `serialize` it or do anything else that will return a valid, unambiguous string representation.

Comment: instead of json_encode you can also just implode the array. Find the fastest way...

Comment: @deceze This is good but the $conversationId changes across different sessions. For example, if I logged in as user1, when I hash the array(1,2,3), the value given is different with the one obtained when I logged in as user2. How do we solve this? Also, are there other solutions which give shorter strings? Thanks.

Comment: @deceze Sorry my bad. I realize the array values were of different type across different sessions. Once I fix that, everything should work. Btw, instead of doing sha1, I'm using crc32 to get a shorter integer-only id. Do you think it is alright? Thanks!